# Parenting two rigs

Tags: rigging

I’m new to blender so I purchased a rigged character. Unfortunately it doesn't have a face rig, so i created one (faces.super_face) in the face samples option. I’ve aligned the armature to the character and now I’m try to parent the face bone of the armature to the head bone of the rig so that it becomes one but when i click Ctrl-P in edit mode i am not getting the “keep offset” option. I did this in blender 2.90 and it didn’t work.

I later tried to parent in blender 3.1, the parent option is in grey and can’t be selected.

I have also tried joining the two rigs in object mode but whichever rig I select first disappears when i click Ctrl-J, i thought that maybe i have constraints or that other bones where hidden in edit mode but i dont have any constraints and all the bones are unhidden. Am i doing something wrong?

Please help me because I’m working on a deadline for a client. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to blender.stackexchange!  You can't parent a bone from one armature onto bones of another armature. However you CAN parent the whole armature-object onto the bone, or you can use a constraint to fake-parent or simply to copy transforms. (I'll try giving a proper answer later...)

Comment: Okay what time can I expect to here from you?

Comment: the best would be to join the 2 armatures, maybe share these 2 armatures so that we can give a try: https://blend-exchange.com/